# expected expression error with stopwatch

Tags: objective-c, xcode, expression, stopwatch

I am quite new to coding and have a error with my current stopwatch method

```
for (int i = [timeArray count] -1; i >= 0; i-) {       <== error here - Expected expression
    int timeComponent = [[timeArray objectAtIndex:i] intValue];
    switch (i) {
        case 3:
            hours = timeComponent;
            break;
        case 2:
            minutes = timeComponent;
            break;
        case 1:
            seconds = timeComponent;
            break;
        case 0:
            hundredths = timeComponent;
            hundredths++;
            break;

        default:
            break;

    }
}
```

I have read up about the incorrect use of a minus - sign but that doesn't seem to fix it

Answer (score 2):

`i-` isn't a valid expression, as the compiler says.  A single `-` is either the unary minus, in which case it has to be *before* your variable, or it's the subtraction operator, in which case you need another variable or constant.

You probably want `i--`, which uses the `--` post-decrement operator and will make your loop work properly.